# Does C++ have a numerical equivalent of a string literal?

Tags: c++, string, literals

String literals are pretty ergonomic, functions with a signature like `int func(const char * str)` can be used simply as `func("I'm a string");`

Is there a function signature or other way to pass numerical data in a similar short-handed way, in one statement contained entirely inside the parameter list of `func()`, similar to how `func({0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF});` might intuitively work, were it a thing?

(It's  `0xEF` terminated)

Comment: See: `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: Or optionally `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: What do you mean by numerical data? A single number or an array of numbers? In the latter case, if you have `foo func(const int *)` you can call it like this: `func((int []){1, 2, 3, 0x4, 0xEF});`

Comment: @HAL9000 [Compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) are a C-only thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - `std::initializer_list` works exactly as I'd like.  I have a question though, does it perform an allocation and copy, or is it similar to a string literal in that it just points into a table in the .exe?

Comment: If you call it as shown, the compiler will probably be able to elide any copying.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude seems to work in `g++`, is that an extension?